# multivariate random variable is constant a.s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ is a multivariate random variable and takes value in $\mathbb{R}^d,d \geq 2,$ and if $F_X$ (distribution function of $X$) only takes two values $0$ and $1$, then $X$ is constant a.s.

Do you have any ideas how to begin?

Comment: Ummm... what is "a.s."?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, "almost surely."

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Step1: To get the marginal distribution of 1 coordinate let all other coordinates go towards infinity.

Step2: Argue that the marginal distribution function can only take values 0 and 1

Step3: Prove it for the 1 dimensional case and argue that if all the marginal distributions are constant almost surely, then so is $X$.

Comment: I get the first step, for example by taking $X=(X_1,...,X_d),$ then $F_{X_1}(x_1)=\lim_{x_2,...,x_d \infty}F_X(x_1,...,x_d)$ and the step three by taking, for example $c=\inf(x \in \mathbb{R},F_{X_1}(x)=1)$ then $X_1=c \ a.s,$ what I don't understand how to prove the step 2?

Comment: If a sequence of numbers in $\{0,1\}$ converges, where can it's limit be? In particular we could choose the sequence $F_X(x_1,n,n,...,n)$ which converges to $F_{X_1}(x_1)$.

Comment: is this true because {0,1} is a closed set ?(this isn't always true for example $\frac{1}{n}$ takes value in ]0,1] and the limit is 0)

Comment: Yes closed sets are also sequentially closed.

Comment: If we supposed that $F_{X}$ takes value in {0;1} on a dense set, the result remains true?